# gradlew assembleDebug works in intellij but not in my terminal

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea, flutter

I am using intellij to run my flutter project when I attempt to run my project in the console I notice the following (btw I am using a mac):

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running 'gradlew assembleDebug'...
```

Now when I go to the terminal inside the project and I run the command - I get  a not found error

```
$ gradlew assembleDebug 
command not found: gradlew
```

Any suggestions on how I can make it run on the terminal as well ?

```
$ ls -l android
total 56
drwxr-xr-x  5 adam  staff   160 Sep 24 00:41 app
-rw-r--r--  1 adam  staff   850 Sep  9 02:18 build.gradle
drwxr-xr-x  2 adam  staff    64 Apr 30 20:38 gen
drwxr-xr-x  3 adam  staff    96 Apr 30 20:38 gradle
-rw-r--r--  1 adam  staff    29 Apr 18 02:24 gradle.properties
-rwxr-xr-x  1 adam  staff  4971 Apr 30 20:38 gradlew
-rw-r--r--  1 adam  staff  2404 Apr 30 20:38 gradlew.bat
-rw-r--r--  1 adam  staff   109 Sep  4 23:54 local.properties
-rw-r--r--  1 adam  staff   484 Apr 18 02:24 settings.gradle
```

Comment: try: `flutter run` - you can add `-v` for it to be verbose

Comment: Well flutter run will work but I am explicitly trying to diagnose an issue here using the command `./gradlew :app:dependencies` thus I want to know why gradlew is not working in the terminal

Comment: try `ls -l android` - what you see? do you see `gradlew` with `-rwxr-xr-x` permissions?

Comment: just updated the post

Comment: so you have `-rwxr-xr-x  1 adam  staff  4971 Apr 30 20:38 gradlew` - then run it

Comment: Yeah just realized I should have been running it from android directory i was running the command from root of my flutter project

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: yes it is solved